# `line` command on unix/linux bash prompt a permission denied infor

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, unix, permissions

Recently, I am learning how to write script code.

I wrote a script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# while3b.sh
while f=`line`
do
        .. process f ..
done < ./myfile
```

and here is `myfile`

```
hello
howdy
gday
bonjour
guten tag 
您好！
*
```

in the terminal,I input this:`sh while3b.sh` and then it prompted some permission information like this.

```
while3b.sh: 4: while3b.sh: ..: Permission denied
while3b.sh: 4: while3b.sh: ..: Permission denied
while3b.sh: 4: while3b.sh: ..: Permission denied
while3b.sh: 4: while3b.sh: ..: Permission denied
while3b.sh: 4: while3b.sh: ..: Permission denied
while3b.sh: 4: while3b.sh: ..: Permission denied
while3b.sh: 4: while3b.sh: ..: Permission denied
while3b.sh: 4: while3b.sh: ..: Permission denied
```

I tried to use `ls -al` to check `rwx` of `myfile`

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 shanechiu shanechiu    48 Jan 31 11:38 myfile
-rwxr-xr-x 1 shanechiu shanechiu    61 Jan 31 11:45 while3b.sh
```

and I used `su - root` to change to super user, then executed while3b.sh script again,the same information showed off. Why?

Could anyone do me a favor? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that it is the line containing the asterisk ("`*`") in your `myfile`.
You evaluate `f` somehow and probably run into trouble when the asterisk is expanded as pattern matching character.

Example:

```
#!/bin/sh
# while3b.sh
while f=`line`
do
        echo $f
done < ./myfile
```

leads to

```
$ ./while3b.sh
hello
howdy
gday
bonjour
guten tag
您好！
myfile myfile~ while3b.sh
```

Because my directory contains the three files `myfile`, `myfile~` and `while3b.sh`. You should examine your code which you abbreviated by "process" what it does when `$f` gets fed with the `*`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it. I just copied it from a tutorial, and your answer reminds me that `process` may be a function. and I omitted this. :)